# Get truth values out of repeating adjectives

Tags: python, wordnet

I have an array with different texts. Some of them have repeating adjectives. Now I want to make an array out of this, that contanes truth values with 1 = text contains a repeating adjective and 0 = text does not contain a repeating adjective. This is a sample of my text:

```py
text = (['When someone who is extremely selfish dramatically
 wonders why people are so selfish !', 'I asked God to 
protect me from my enemies .. shortly after I started losing friends'])
```

So far I tried to get the type of a word with wordnet

```py
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

my_list = []
for synset in list(wn.all_synsets('a')):
    my_list.append(synset)
my_list

truth_values = []
for sentence in text:
    for word in sentence:
        if word in my_list:
            truth_values.append(1)
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute '_name'
```

For the dublicate condition I thougt of a counter like

```
if counter >=1:
    truth_value.append(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you, so let's go through a few of the bugs that were existing in your code:

Writing `list(wn.all_synsets('a')` will return a list of all adjectives as Synset objects, but what you really want is the string of the name of the adjective. Calling `synset.name()` returns data in this format: `acroscopic.a.01`. Since we only want the first part of that (and as a string), we will change

```
for synset in list(wn.all_synsets('a')):
    my_list.append(synset)
```

to

```
for synset in list(wn.all_synsets('a')):
    my_list.append(str(synset.name()).split(".")[0])
```

So now we have the desired list of all adjectives. Now, notice that the line

```
for word in sentence:
```

is parsing the individual characters in the sentence rather than words. What we want is

```
for word in sentence.split(" "):
```

All that said, here is how I would solve this problem:

```
truth_values = []
for sentence in text:
    adjectives = []
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word in my_list:
            adjectives.append(word)
    truth_values.append(1 if any(adjectives.count(adj) > 1 for adj in adjectives) else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all adjectives, it may be tricky. The best approach is using a language parser, like the stanford statistical parser. It will result in the grammar function of each word at the sentences. You can also use spacy.

```
import spacy

# Load English tokenizer, tagger, parser, NER and word vectors
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Process whole documents
text = ("When someone who is extremely selfish dramatically"
        "wonders why people are so selfish !")
doc = nlp(text)

# Analyze syntax
adj = [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ == "ADJ"]
repeat = len(adj) != len(set(adj))
print("Adjectives:", adj)
print("Repeats?", repeat)
```

Try running your approach with the sentence: "I didn't mean what you mean when you say that". It fails, but with this other approach it doesn't. The reason is that 'mean' *can* be a adjective, but not always it is.